# codeigniter, cannot update value on database

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have some trouble to update records using active records in codeigniter

here's my model

```
function update_balance_trans($balance,$kodebooking)
{
        $data = array(
                       'BALANCE' => intval($balance)
                    );

        $this->db->where('BOOKING_NO', $kodebooking);
        $this->db->update('transactions', $data); 

}
```

and here's my controller

```
$this->app_model->update_balance_trans($totaltarif,$book_code);
```

and my model is already autoload on

```
$autoload['model'] = array('app_model');
```

but the field BALANCE in the transactions table is still empty, does anyone can help ?

Comment: are you sure you're updating the correct data?

Comment: Just to be on safer side, check if `$balance` is `int` not `String`.

Comment: try echo $this->db->last_query() after update in model then check your query is ok or your having any mistake.

Comment: @hussain, i already convert it with intval()

Comment: did you try to return values from update_balance_trans function before database operation? Does it work ?

Answer (score 0):

conf is good in database.php?

```
<?php 
 $db['default']['hostname'] = '127.0.0.1';
    $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
    $db['default']['password'] = 'root';
    $db['default']['database'] = 'bdd';
    $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
    $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
    $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
    $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
    $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
    $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
    $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
    $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: yes, but mine just got one $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

Do this on your method

```
   //new construct method 
   function __construct()
    { 
       $this->load->database();

    }

function update_balance_trans($balance,$kodebooking)
{
        $data = array(
                       'BALANCE' => intval($balance)
                    );

        //new lines
        print_r($data);
        print_r($kodebooking);
        die();


        $this->db->where('BOOKING_NO', $kodebooking);
        $this->db->update('transactions', $data); 

}
```

let me know the result

Comment: here's the result -> Array ( [BALANCE] => 70000 )

Comment: here's the result -> Array ( [BALANCE] => 70000 ) 60JPT0

Comment: seem nothing wrong with the code, you might want to check with database connection

Comment: here's the configuration :

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';
$db['default']['database'] = 'cta_db';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';

Comment: $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

Comment: default for SQL username ('root') and password('') meaning none;

Comment: in my localhost, mysql user is 'root' and password is 'root' (without quote)

Comment: Can you please write $this->db->last_query();die(); after  $this->db->update('transactions', $data); and check your query.

Comment: i've got blank on my browser, i already make sure that 'display_errors = on' on the php.ini, and restart my apache server at least 5 times, but stll blank on my browser

Answer (score 0):

Please check your db connection again. Something is wrong with that only. Try using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1. Also cross check the username and password. If its local, the password might be blank.

Comment: see my conversations with Wayne Tun

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();
     $this->load->database();
}    


function update_balance_trans($balance,$kodebooking)
    {


  $data = array(
                   'BALANCE' => intval($balance)
                );

    $this->db->where('BOOKING_NO', $kodebooking);
    $this->db->update('transactions', $data); 

    echo $this->db->last_query(); 

}
```

Post me the Query ..

Comment: i've got blank on my browser, i already make sure that 'display_errors = on' on the php.ini, and restart my apache server at least 5 times, but stll blank on my browser

Comment: Are you getting the blank screen by adding this line (echo $this->db->last_query(); )  ?

Answer (score 0):

Just Try Like this !!

```
$query = "UPDATE transactions SET BALANCE = '70000' WHERE BOOKING_NO = ".$kodebooking;

$this->db->query($query);
```